# How to put a "session" time out for a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, time, timeout, clock

Is there something like a session time out in python in between lines of code or in between calling a function? Something like this:

```
threshold = 20
def afunction(input):
  start_session
  try:
    do_something...
    return x
  except SessionTimeOut:
    return y
```

Comment: a possible [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call/494273)